# List of relocatables integrated into static library

Tags: c, go

Below archive file(`shuffler.a`) is created with below command:

```
$ go install github.com/myhub/cs61a
$
$
$ file pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/myhub/cs61a/shuffler.a
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/myhub/cs61a/shuffler.a: current ar archive
$ 
$
```

---

But there is more than one than file(relocatable) integrated in archive file:

```
$ ar -t pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/myhub/cs61a/shuffler.a 
__.PKGDEF
_go_.o
$
$
```

---

`_go_.o` is a relocatable binary form of `src/github.com/myhub/cs61a/shuffler/shuffle.go` source code

What  does `__.PKGDEF` signify? `ar –rcs libourown.c one.o two.o` in C world does not add this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since go code is organized by package, while C code is not, and since go libraries/binaries are compiled package by package, I would take the wild guess that PKGDEF has information about the go language package from which the code was compiled.

Comment: After `ar x`, I could not read `__.PKGDEF` as human readable  file

Comment: not surprising, contents of an object file or archive are not expected to be human-readable.  Linkers and compilers will read it.